# Is that Black Panther with an Infinity Gauntlet?

Tags: marvel, marvel-contest-of-champions

If you jump to 1:30 of this video, you'll find a being fighting with Thanos and both are equipped with an Infinity Gauntlet.

Who is he? Is he really wearing an Infinity Gauntlet? **I thought two fully-equipped Infinity Gauntlets can't exist at the same time.**

Comment: Looks like Black Panther, and looks like an Infinity Gauntlet. However, this seems to be a promotional video for a mobile fighting game, so I don't know why you'd expect it to adhere to canon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed Black Panther and we can see him wielding the *[Infinity Claw](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/4/49/Erik_Stevens_%28Earth-TRN662%29_from_Marvel_Contest_of_Champions_001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180219061646)*.

Note that this item (which is exclusive to Contest of Champions) is from an alternate reality and as such **is powerful, but doesn't confer near-omnipotence on the wielder.**

Comment: Infinity Claw!! Seriously?!

Comment: Most likely a promotion for Avengers: Endgame, curious to see if it eventually migrates over to comics.